# Suppress warnings for annotated fields not working in IntelliJ 2016.3

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

By default IntelliJ is marking `Autowired` fields as unused. I tried to get rid of that by Alt+Enter -> `Suppress for fields annotated by 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired'`, but they're still showing up as unused.

In Settings -> Inspections -> Java -> Declaration redundancy -> Unused declarations I verified that `Autowired` [got marked as entry point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0AXc.png) several times (I clicked `Suppress` more than once), but it's not helping. Removing and adding entry point again also doesn't help.

My setup is OS X El Capitan, IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2, JRE 1.8.0_112

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was necessary to manually add `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired` to "Mark field as implicitly written" in inspection configuration window.

It was posted by someone before but the answer was deleted, more details at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164948#comment=27-1770016

Comment: Would you mind pointing out how to get to the inspection configuration window?  I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it.  It's pretty buried in idea 2016.3.    Go to Settings -> Inspections.  Select your inspection (ie, Unused declaration).  Select the Entry points tab, click annotations.  Add the Autowired class to the "Mark field as implicitly written" section.

Answer (score 1):

Put your cursor on the warning and then alt+enter and choose one from the suppress warning options. You can choose between suppressing this warning for only this field or whole file etc.

Comment: This is the first thing I did as described in the question. It just kept adding to mark Autowired annotation as Entry point, but the warning didn't disappear.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore since IDEA 2016.3 (or even .2)